# ExpressJS apply JWT for file url

Tags: express, jwt

So I'm trying to make authorization for routes with JWT, it all worked if used on routes.

```
app.get('/user/list', jwtMiddleware, action);
```

And the jwtMiddleware content is (more or less):

```
var token = req.headers.authorization;
    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_TOKEN, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(401).send({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Sign in to continue.'
                });
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(401).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Sign in to continue.'
        });
    }
```

it works, but I have these image files in **uploads/** folder which accessible by **/upload/image-1.jpg** and I want to prevent direct access to **/upload/image-1.jpg** by using wildcard routes `app.get('/upload*', jwtMiddleware, action);`

then I try accessing random route with **upload** prefix like **/upload/test**, the jwt middleware works. But if I explicitly type **/upload/image-1.jpg** the browser just show the image, it's like the middleware or wildcard route (**/upload***) is not accessed (the console.log inside middleware didn't even fired).

Previously I use **restify** and **restify-jwt-middleware**, it could handle this case flawlessly but in **express** I can't find out why it doesn't work. Maybe because **restify-jwt-middleware** automatically registers all routes into jwt validation whereas **express** need to declare each route with jwt middleware manually.

is there anything I miss in this case? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add/modify to another route like `app.get('/upload/:image', jwtMiddleware, action)`

this will check all the route you mentioned `/upload/*`

**EDIT :**
put the static files(eg.uploaded files somewhere like `images/upload`) and route them using the serveStaticFiles plugin restify and put jwt middleware to verify the user login status.

```
server.get(
  '/uploads/*', 
  jwtMiddleware,
  restify.plugins.serveStaticFiles('./images/upload')
);
```

Comment: nope, the image still shows up (directly accessed) and middleware doesn't triggered

Comment: are you serving the static files directly?

Comment: @A-SM check the recent addition.

Comment: yes, you last edit is the same solution I've found after searching for a whole day, I was about to write the answer myself but I'm glad you also have similar solution I approve that this is a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still confused, here's my answer in **express** which is similar approach to yathomasi's

```
// the fake route
app.get('uploads/:name', jwtMiddleware, (req, res, next) => {
    if (fs.existsSync('./realpath/' + req.params.name)) {
        res.sendFile('./realpath/' + req.params.name);
    } else {
        res.status(404).body({status : 'ERROR', message : 'File not found'});
    }
});
```

this way, the **uploads/somefile.jpg** is treated as route url not file url and will be processed by **jwtMiddleware**